# Swift closed interval global array

Tags: swift, global, intervals

Is there a way in swift to have a global variable that is an array of closed intervals and can it start as an empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be describing something like this:

```
var arr = Array<ClosedInterval<Double>>()
```

And then later:

```
let r = 1.0...3.0
let r2 = 4.0...6.0
arr.append(r)
arr.append(r2)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified before, I am trying to use a closed interval since I can't pass a double to a range